# Login con FOSUserBundle, HWIOAuthBundle y symfony 3.4 error An authentication exception occurred

Tags: php, symfony3, fos-user-bundle

Hola estoy integrando un logeo de facebook y google en un proyecto con Symfony 3.4 con  [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) version ~2.0, para eso estoy usando [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) en su version ^0.6.3. me guié por este [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697)
y lo complete con la documentacion [Bonus: Facebook Connect](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/bonus/facebook-connect.md) pero luego de loguear me da el error: "An authentication exception occurred." 
Por lo que entiendo luego de dar click al loguear deberia pasar por el FOSUBUserProvider y guardar los datos en la base de datos pero no lo esta haciendo.

Acá les dejo parte del código

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: xxxxxx@gmail.com
        sender_name: "xxxx"
httplug:
    clients:
        default:
            factory: 'httplug.factory.curl'
        hwi_special:
            factory: 'httplug.factory.guzzle6'
            config: # You pass here the Guzzle configuration, exactly like before.
                timeout: 10
                verify: false

hwi_oauth:
    http:
        client: httplug.client.hwi_special
    connect:
        account_connector: my_user_provider
    # name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    firewall_name: main
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            # these properties will be used/redefined later in the custom FOSUBUserProvider service.
            facebook: facebookId
            google: googleId
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           "%facebook_app_id%"
            client_secret:       "%facebook_app_secret%"
            scope:         "email"
            options:
                display: popup #dialog is optimized for popup window
                auth_type: rerequest # Re-asking for Declined Permissions
        google:
            type:                google
            client_id:           "%google_app_id%"
            client_secret:       "%google_app_secret%"
            scope:               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    # here you will add one (or more) configurations for resource owners
```

routing.yml

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
#HWIOAuthBundle routes
hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /login

facebook_login:
    path: /login/check-facebook

google_login:
    path: /login/check-google
```

services.yml

```
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value
    my_user_provider.class: AppBundle\Security\FOSUBUserProvider
services:
my_user_provider:
        class: "%my_user_provider.class%"
        #this is the place where the properties are passed to the UserProvider - see config.yml
        arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager',{facebook: facebook_id, google: google_id}]
authentication.handler.login_success_handler:
        class:  AppBundle\Security\LoginSuccessHandler
        arguments:  ['@router', '@security.authorization_checker']
```

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                success_handler: authentication.handler.login_success_handler
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                    google:             "/login/check-google"
                login_path:        /login
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    #this is my custom user provider, created from FOSUBUserProvider - will manage the
                    #automatic user registration on your site, with data from the provider (facebook. google, etc.)
                    service: my_user_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            logout_on_user_change: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/config, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        #- { path: ^/carrito, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

y en mi entidad agregue lo siguiente:

```
/** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebookId;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_access_token;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $googleId;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $google_access_token;


    /**
     * Set facebookId
     *
     * @param string $facebookId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFacebookId($facebookId)
    {
        $this->facebookId = $facebookId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get facebookId
     *
     * @param string $facebookId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getFacebookId($facebookId)
    {
        $this->facebookId = $facebookId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set facebook_access_token
     *
     * @param string $facebook_access_token
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFacebookAccessToken($facebook_access_token)
    {
        $this->facebook_access_token = $facebook_access_token;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get facebook_access_token
     *
     * @param string $facebook_access_token
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getFacebookAccessToken($facebook_access_token)
    {
        $this->facebook_access_token = $facebook_access_token;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Set googleId
     *
     * @param string $googleId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setGoogleId($googleId)
    {
        $this->googleId = $googleId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get googleId
     *
     * @param string $googleId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getGoogleId($googleId)
    {
        $this->googleId = $googleId;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Set google_access_token
     *
     * @param string $google_access_token
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setGoogleAccessToken($google_access_token)
    {
        $this->google_access_token = $google_access_token;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get google_access_token
     *
     * @param string $google_access_token
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getGoogleAccessToken($google_access_token)
    {
        $this->google_access_token = $google_access_token;

        return $this;
    }
```

y en mi login agregue lo siguiente:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fb_login();">Facebook Connect Button (Dialog)</a>
```

y el script

```
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'https://www.XXXXXX.com./login/check-facebook',      // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function fb_login() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                    alert('Already connected, redirect to login page to create token.');
                    document.location = '{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}';
                } else {
                    // not_authorized
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            document.location = '{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}';
                        } else {
                            alert('Cancelled.');
                        }
                    }, {scope: 'email'});
                }
            });
        }
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            /*console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
            console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
            console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
            console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
            console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

            // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
            var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);*/
            //document.location = '{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "google"}) }}';
          }
    </script>
```

Comment: Habría que ver los logs para determinar cuál sería el problemta, pero mira este comentario dentro del tutorial que indicaste https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697#gistcomment-814865
Básicamente utiliza twig para el link de login 

    `<a href="{{ path('hwi_oauth_service_redirect', {'service': 'facebook' }) }}" alt="Sign in with Facebook">Sign in with Facebook</a>`

Comment: los logs no me arrojan nada :/... con respecto a link de login ya lo probe y me da exactamente el mismo error.